# JAVA Bitwise code purpose , &

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

```
// following code prints out Letters aA bB cC dD eE ....

class UpCase {
public static void main(String args[]) {
 char ch;

 for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  ch = (char)('a' + i);
  System.out.print(ch);

  ch = (char)((int) ch & 66503);

  System.out.print(ch + " ")
  }
 }
}
```

Still learning Java but struggling to understand bitwise operations. Both codes work but I don't understand the binary reasons behind these codes. Why is (int) casted back to ch and what is 66503 used for that enables it to print out different letter casings.

```
//following code displays bits within a byte

class Showbits {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
  int t;
  byte val;

  val = 123;
  for(t = 128; t > 0; t = t/2) {
   if((val & t) != 0) 
    System.out.print("1 ");
    else System.out.print("0 ");
   }

  }
 }
 //output is 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1
```

For this code's output what's the step breakdown to achieve it ? If 123 is 01111011 and 128 as well as 64 and 32 is 10000000 shouldnt the output be 00000000 ? As & turns anything with 0 into a 0 ? Really confused.

Comment: *"128 as well as 64 and 32 is 10000000"* Why do you think three different numbers are the same number?

Comment: Thats what it shows on most online binary converters maybe a few difference in zeros

Comment: *"maybe a few difference in zeros"* lol Tell that to my bank account if you think 100 and 100000 are the same number.

Comment: Thats why I'm asking as I'm learning and understanding if I could be wrong. Do you go to the doctor and ask him for flu medication but find out you have Cancer instead cause you "thought" the symptoms were similar ? Some stuff could be the same thing but have different meaning, I don't know yet, everyones learning relax pal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Second piece of code(Showbits):**

The code is actually converting [decimal to binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#Decimal). The algorithm uses some bit magic, mainly the [AND(&) operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND).

Consider the number `123 = 01111011` and `128 = 10000000`. When we AND them together, we get `0` or a non-zero number depending whether the `1` in `128` is AND-ed with a `1` or a `0`.

```
  10000000
& 01111011
----------
  00000000
```

In this case, the answer is a `0` and we have the first bit as 0.
Moving forward, we take `64 = 01000000` and, AND it with `123`. Notice the shift of the `1` rightwards.

```
  01000000
& 01111011
----------
  01000000
```

AND-ing with 123 produces a non-zero number this time, and the second bit is 1. This procedure is repeated.

**First piece of code(UpCase):**

Here 65503 is the [negation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#NOT) of 32.

```
 32 = 0000 0000 0010 0000
~32 = 1111 1111 1101 1111
```

Essentially, we subtract a value of 32 from the lowercase letter by AND-ing with the negation of 32. As we know, subtracting 32 from a lowercase ASCII value character converts it to uppercase.

Comment: Thanks man clear and concise explanation. Finally manage to piece it together

Answer (score 0):

**UpCase**

The decimal number `66503` represented by a 32 bit signed integer is `00000000 00000001 00000011 11000111` in binary.

The ASCII letter `a` represented by a 8 bit char is `01100001` in binary (97 in decimal).

Casting the char to a 32 bit signed integer gives `00000000 00000000 00000000 01100001`.

`&`ing the two integers together gives:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 01100001
00000000 00000001 00000011 11000111
===================================
00000000 00000000 00000000 01000001
```

which casted back to char gives `01000001`, which is decimal 65, which is the ASCII letter `A`.

**Showbits**

No idea why you think that `128`, `64` and `32` are all `10000000`. They obviously can't be the same number, since they are, well, different numbers. `10000000` is `128` in decimal.

What the for loop does is start at `128` and go through every consecutive next smallest power of 2: `64`, `32`, `16`, `8`, `4`, `2` and `1`.

These are the following binary numbers:

```
128: 10000000
 64: 01000000
 32: 00100000
 16: 00010000
  8: 00001000
  4: 00000100
  2: 00000010
  1: 00000001
```

So in each loop it `&`s the given value together with each of these numbers, printing `"0 "` when the result is `0`, and `"1 "` otherwise.

Example:

`val` is `123`, which is `01111011`.

So the loop will look like this:

```
128: 10000000 & 01111011 = 00000000 -> prints "0 "
 64: 01000000 & 01111011 = 01000000 -> prints "1 "
 32: 00100000 & 01111011 = 00100000 -> prints "1 "
 16: 00010000 & 01111011 = 00010000 -> prints "1 "
  8: 00001000 & 01111011 = 00001000 -> prints "1 "
  4: 00000100 & 01111011 = 00000000 -> prints "0 "
  2: 00000010 & 01111011 = 00000010 -> prints "1 "
  1: 00000001 & 01111011 = 00000001 -> prints "1 "
```

Thus the final output is `"0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1"`, which is exactly right.